# Creating a vector for multiple observations in R

Tags: r

I have a similar table as shown in this example (mine has more variables but the problem remains the same). I need observations taken in the same counties to be given the same index, and stored in J

[image]

I need to create the vector J as shown on the right hand side of the picture, can anybody help me with this? The table can be found [here](https://ufile.io/l68mq6t8). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you would just use your county column?

`j = randomdata$county` which you can subset as `j[919]` and get 85.